# Dynamic Array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Hi i have an application with lot of textboxes to be filled with data from user.My goal for now is to make a dynamic array and with one function to check the inputed data.If the inputed data wont pass some logical "If" (like in date text box the inputed year will be 1867) will be stored in my dynamic array.My question is how to populate the dynamic array in my function with my application variables and how the return statement will be in my application?

```
 With 
   objTest.testCode = FrmHeader.txtEOPtestCode.Text 'That's my input
   'In my function 
   if objTest.testCode > 100 then
        'getvalue into my dynamic array.
```

i am missing how to populate my dynamic array and how to return it correctly.
Also the main reason for this is to finally call my function before my

```
  Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter (My.Settings.PathToShared & "\Test\Test - Saved.xml")
```

to get the inputed data before saving in my xml.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Add some example code of what are your input, checks and expected returns. Also look at List (It is a better choice than an array)

Comment: You should enable option strict...